# How to overlap a image in responsive slider?

Tags: css

I need to overlap image of logo 20px down in a responsive slider. The image of logo must come at front and the responsive slider must be back. Please view live at: http://www.pahari.com.np

```
**HTML PART:**
<div id="top_banner"> <div id="logo"><img src="image/logo.jpg"> </div> </div>
<div id="slider_bg"> <?php include_once("slider.php"); ?> </div>
<div id="menu_bg"> </div>
<div id="content_bg"> <div id="content"> </div> </div>


**CSS PART:**
<style>
#top_banner{
width: 1000px;
height: 106px;
margin: auto;
}
#logo{
width: 362px;
background: url(images/logo.jpg) no-repeat;
height: 106px;
float: left;
}
#slider_bg{
float: left;
height: 380px;
}
#menu_bg{
background: #B1BB34;
height: 30px;
}
#content_bg{
background: #A562B1;
height: 180px;
margin-top: 25px;
}
#content{
background: url("image/bg.jpg") no-repeat;
width: 1000px;
margin: auto;
height: 180px;
margin-top: 25px;
}
<style>
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle and post the link?

Comment: This is only and image and therefore not very useful. Please create a fiddle or at least properly build the site on your own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to position your `slider1_container` with a negative value for top and adding a negative z-index. ex.:

```
top:-2em;
z-index:-1
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the top banner in another div and work with absolute positioning. Please note that I have taken only part of your code for display purposes on fiddle. You will need to add this to your site accordingly.

**Check this out:** **http://jsfiddle.net/3Z2JZ/**

**CSS**

```
body{
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) #FFFFFF repeat-x;
    font: normal 12px verdana;
    color: #9C9C9C;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#top_banner_wrap {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
}

#top_banner{
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 106px;
    margin: auto;
}
#logo{
    width: 362px;
    background: url(images/logo.jpg) no-repeat;
    height: 106px;
    float: left;
}
#slider_bg{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 380px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 86px;
}
```

Comment: But still logo image is overlapped by responsive slider. The above solution given by morgul worked. Thanx for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
#logo {
       position: relative; 
       z-index:100;
}
```

for the logo element and it will stay on top of the slider element.z-index should be highest number defined.